# convert map<String,Map<Long,customeObject>> to list<customeobject> using java 8

Tags: java

can somebody help me converting `Map<String, map<Long, Set<PanelData>>>` to `List<PanelData>`?

Backgroud: as part of my task I have grouped the `PanelData` object on two different attributes and the end result is the above map. `PanelData` is just a POJO with getter and setter.

Comment: ConcurrentMap<String, ConcurrentMap<Long, Set<PanelData>>>  to list of

Comment: Map<String, Map<Long, Set<PanelData>>> to list<PanelData>

Comment: Just edit your question, don't put in comments and provide more on , what have you tried so far

Answer (score 2):

To convert a `Map<String,Map<Long,CustomObject>>` to `List<CustomObject>`, you can do it somewhat like this:

```
Map<String,Map<Long,CustomObject>> input = ...
List<CustomObject> output = new ArrayList<>();
input.forEach((key, value) -> output.addAll(value.values()));
```

Comment: @AbidRahut If it did help, do accept it as an answer to it could be useful for others as well :)

Answer (score 1):

You can get stream from `entrySet` and use `flatMap` to make another stream from `values`:

```
map.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```